# How do I use cluster manager with android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, markerclusterer

I have an android app that allows a user to add markers to the map where ever they pressed and hold. The map also pulls markers information, such as latlng, title, description, etc from a database, and creates a marker on the map. The markers use a custom info window and have functions when clicked on and long clicked on.  There is an unlimited amount of markers that can be put on the map.  I want to incorporate marker clustering to the app.  I have added google maps utiltiy library.  However, there is not very much information out there to show how to use the library to cluster markers together. I was hoping someone knows of any resources out there that can help me learn how to use cluster manager.

I have looked at the developer page, https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/marker-clustering, and followed the simple clustering tutorial, but that does not help me with figuring out how to incorporate all the information I have into the markers.

Any help would be very grateful!

Comment: You can look at this GitHub link for another example https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/clustering/ClusterManager.java

Comment: Fill the clustermanager in de onMapReady() method? show some code.